# How should I translate "he is a pain in the ass"?

Tags: traducción, coloquialismos

When referring to someone you don't like Americans (or English speakers) often use the sentence "he is a pain the ass". The literal translation to the Spanish is

> (Él) es un dolor en el trasero

However, at least in Mexico is not used like that. Some sentences I can think of but wouldn't say that they denote the same feeling are:

- Me cae mal.
- Es una piedra en el zapato.

How should I translate “he is a pain in the ass”?

Comment: Quick comment: Es una _china_ en el zapato. _China_ also means small stone.

Comment: so is that actually used on Spain as well? Interesting...

Comment: Not that much, quite uncommon for people and barely used. But would be understood without difficulty.

Comment: The answers probably depend on the dialect, as this is a common enough phrase that each place has its own way of saying it.

Comment: Since this is a colloquial expression it's best to translate into the colloquial Spanish of the region where you want to express it, which will vary greatly from place to place. How best to say it in a way that works for all Spanish speakers is a good question though.

Comment: Es un dolor de huevos (offensive, Mexico)

Comment: @Serabe: Depends on the region. But as I know it, china means Marble (little glass ball with colors).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are many many ways to say this, here are some examples:
(With the help of other answers, more like a compilation)

Be aware it really depends on where you are, although most will be understood in all the spanish speaking countries. If you use one from another place you will likely receive a **you are an outsider look**

Argentina:

- hincha-pelotas

Colombia:

- huevón
- jodón
- cansón

Ecuador:

- molestoso
- cabrón

México:

- cabrón (vulgar)
- Es un hígado
- mamón

Perú:

- jodido
- espeso
- ladilla

Venezuela:

- ladilla

España:

- Como un grano en el culo.
- porculero (vulgar)
- cansino

Source:

[Insultos regionales](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikcionario%3aInsultos_regionales)

Comment: @Joze Perú: jodido, espeso, ladilla

Comment: You can add: porculero (very vulgar), pesao, cansino, toca-pelotas, to the Spanish list.

Comment: Also: pesado (less offensive than hincha-pelotas) in Argentina.

Comment: In Mexico: Non swearing ways - "es un hígado", "es insoportable". Swearing ways - "es un mamón", "es un jodón". And as a side note, if you are in Mexico "Guevón" has a different meaning, is a very impolite way of saying that the person es extremely lazy.

Comment: @SergioRomero It is "huevón". I already corrected it.

Comment: @Rellikiox: Never heard "porculero" after 40 years in Spain. Must be a regional thing.

Comment: Northeast México we also say "patada en los huevos"

Answer (score 8):

Despite the good answers also is worth to mention the following expression:

> Es un dolor de cabeza.

Spanish has a wide variety of ways to say the same thing (specially bad things).

Usage example:

> Fulanito es un dolor de cabeza, siempre hace ...

Comment: +1 for the universality of this translation, and I think it really captures the spirit of "pain in the ass." A lot of the other ones would be (at least for me) closer to just "bothersome," which of course would lead you to being a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 5):

"es un hincha-pelotas" if we want to keep the translation in the lower area of the body XD

It might be only used in south america

Comment: I like your answer better than mine. I don't know if it's used a lot outside Argentina, though.

Comment: In Uruguay is used as well.

Comment: haha nice one +1

Comment: not even whole of South America, it's mostly Argentinian

Answer (score 4):

In Spain a similar one would be:

> Es como un grano en el culo.

Answer (score 2):

"Aquel se pone gorro" is another option. The word "gorro" directly translates to bonnet, but the slang on the Texas/Mexican border is as such that it basically means  he overshadows you. It comes from the old habit of a mother forcing a child to wear a bonnet to protect your head and is unwanted but you just can't get rid of it as it is tied to you.

Comment: *Gorro* is “bonnet” for you?  Really? What do you mean by bonnet? Isn’t that a fancy thing a lady wears? I should think *un gorro* is a hat while *una gorra* is like a baseball cap type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

- Es un pelmazo.
- Es un pesado.
- etc.

Comment: yeah, just **pesado** is very common in spain, or **pesao** in its slang form :)

Answer (score 1):

[The English Wiktionary has a couple of variants.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pain_in_the_ass#Translations)

> Spanish: patada en las bolas, patada en los huevos

My Larouuse gran diccionario has translations for several English variants:

> **he's a pain (in the neck)** es un plomazo *or* pelmazo *or Méx* sangrón; *US Fam* **to give sb a pain (in the neck)** dar la paliza a alguien; *Vulg* **it's a pain in the** *Br* arse *or US* **ass** es *Esp* un coñazo *or Méx* una chingadera *or RP* un embole